# How do I hide a non-visual component on a form at design-time?

Tags: delphi

I am working on the GUI of an older program (in Delphi). Some of the forms are small and have a number of non-visual components on them (UDP servers, UDP clients etc). I'm sure I used to be able to hide/show the non-visual components on the form with a hot-key, but I can't remember what it was. It may have been in an add-in that I have not added-in since upgrading to XE. Does anyone know where/what this might be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This option is included inside of the [Gexperts](http://www.gexperts.org/download.html) menu and is called `Hide/Show Non-Visual`.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I remember now! Cheers. Looks like I'll be downloading Gexperts then.

Answer (score 5):

A rather drastic measure would be to upgrade to Delphi 10 Seattle (or later) as this is one of the new features that Embarcadero have added.  There is a small button next to "Toggle Form/Unit" called "Show/Hide Non-Visual Components" - the shortcut is CTRL+H

[image: Show/Hide Non-Visual Components button]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any feature like this in any version of Delphi. However, GExperts has such a feature.

Comment: +1. @David: With no link and no image, surely you didn't expect an upvote just because you were the first one to give the correct answer, did you? ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is not built into Delphi but it is provided by [GExperts.](http://www.gexperts.org/)
It only works for `TCustomForm` based designers.   It will not work for `TDataModule` or other types of designers.

Answer (score 1):

As answered before, GExperts and Delphi 10+ provides such function.
I can also add [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) and my own [small component](https://github.com/DzmitryiK/TNonVisualCompList).