# How to show/hide non-visual components names?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe7

Does *Delphi XE7* have an option for showing/hiding the non visual components names?

I don't want to [completely hide the non-visual components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922227/how-do-i-hide-a-non-visual-component-on-a-form-at-design-time) but I would like to hide the label with their names. It was the default appearance of non visual components in *Delphi 2007* designer:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the option in `Tools -> Options -> Environment Options -> Form Designer -> Show component captions`

[image]

Comment: @Febrizio, oddly I was searching to do the exact opposite. I didn't know I could do it with Delphi6. Great help.